# how to aes decrypt in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I'm trying to get the data decoded using Node native methods, I search how to achieve this but it get **invalid iv initialization** or **Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data** trying differents iv

1. aes-128 ->  16 bytes

it results in ->

> {  "statusCode": 500,
> "message": "Invalid initialization vector" }

```
let decoded: string = '';
for (let ndx = 0; ndx < hash.length; ndx += 2) {
  let i = parseInt('0x' + hash.substring(ndx, ndx + 2));
  decoded += String.fromCharCode(i);
}

try {
  const password = 'somePassword';
  const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 16);
  const iv = Buffer.alloc(11, password, 'ascii'); // Initialization vector.
  const iv2 = crypto.randomBytes(32)
  const iv3 = iv2.toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
  const iv4 = Buffer.allocUnsafe(32)
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-gcm', key, iv);

  let decrypted = decipher.update(decoded, 'ascii', 'utf8');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
```

I'tried many iv but all of them results in ->

> Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data

Comment: You keep changing your code. Please do not do this, especially if there are already answers, as this is difficult for subsequent readers to follow. If changes/additions are necessary, add them to the end of the original post (e.g. marked with an *Edit* or *Update*).

Comment: In your now 6 changes you have changed almost everything that can be changed, e.g. mode, IV size, encoding,.... Such haphazard changes indicate that you are not aware of the encryption. In this case, implementing decryption might be difficult because a decryption is tailored exactly to the encryption and there are many possibilities. Post the encryption code or a detailed description of the encryption.

Comment: as I answer to Maarten Bodewes I recieve encrypted data from a encryption method in informix wich don't give any information on how it encrypt the data because it has it own decrypt method see the link below, I take the advice to not change many times the question...

Comment: Without more details about the encryption, it might be difficult to implement the decryption. Regarding the error messages: *Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data* is thrown if authentication fails (e.g. if no authentication tag was set with `setAuthTag()` during decryption), *invalid iv initialization* possibly because an IV size not supported by the mode was used (e.g. you applied a 16 bytes IV for CCM in one of your attempts, but this only supports IVs between 7 and 13 bytes).

Comment: @Topaco You shouldn't suggest people to mark changes to their question with "edit" or "update". An edited question should look as if it was posted that way from the start, and not be cluttered with edit/update markers. If an edit deviates so much it invalidates existing answers, it should be rolled back with a comment to ask the OP to ask follow ups as a new question. If multiple things are tried, then they should simply be listed one after the other (additive editing).

Comment: See also [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

AES always has a block size of 128. So if we're talking about AES-128, -192 or -256 then the number indicates the key size *in bits*.

So if you specify `aes-128-ccm` then the expected key size is 128 / 8 = 16 bytes. Either you'll have to specify `aes-192-ccm` or the key size needs to be 16 rather than 24 in your `scryptSync` function. Which one is correct depends of course on how the encryption is performed.

Comment: I updated the question after your response and now dont accept the iv parameter

Comment: I can't know more on how the data is encrypted because comes from a sentence in data base -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=encryption-encrypting-column-data

Answer (score 0):

```
    const crypto = require('crypto');

const encryptedData = '<your_encrypted_data>'; 
const iv = Buffer.from('<your_iv>', 'base64'); 


const password = 'somePassword';
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 16); // 16 bytes key for AES-128

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);

decipher.setEncoding('utf8');

let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedData, 'base64', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(decrypted);
```

Comment: I need to create a new iv, I don't recieve it from informix database encrypt method -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=encryption-encrypting-column-data